# My KeyBindings don't work and I want to know why

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I have just started on learning how to use keyBindings and I cannot find out what I am doing wrong as when I press the UP arrow on my keyboard it does nothing.

**My Main Game Window**

```
public class GameWindow extends JFrame{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public int WIDTH = 160, HEIGHT = WIDTH/12 *9, SCALE = 3;

public boolean running = false;

BackGround bg = new BackGround();

Ranger R = new Ranger();

TimerClass T = new TimerClass();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GameWindow();

}

public GameWindow() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);
    setResizable(false);

    running = true;

    add(bg);
    bg.add(R);

    bg.setFocusable(true);

    R.setFocusable(true);

    setFocusable(true);
    setVisible(true);
    bg.repaint();

    run();
}

public void run() {
    while (running) {
        render();
    }
}

public void render() {
    bg.setLocation(Ranger.bgX, Ranger.bgY);
    R.setLocation(Ranger.X, Ranger.Y);
    R.setIcon(Ranger.rangerA[Ranger.I]);
    R.repaint();
    bg.repaint();
}

}
```

**And My Ranger Class**

```
public class Ranger extends JLabel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static int X, Y, dX, dY, bgX, bgY, I = 0, jumpTime = 100;

public static boolean moving = false, movingLeft = false,
        movingRight = false, onFloor = false, jumping = false,
        movingUp = false, movingDown = false;

public int totalImages = 6;

public BufferedImage ranger1, ranger2, ranger3, ranger4, ranger5, ranger6;

public static ImageIcon[] rangerA;

static TileMap TileMap = new TileMap();

public Ranger() {

    try {
        // not moving
        ranger1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(
                "/Images/Sprites/ranger/Ranger0.png"));
        ranger2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(
                "/Images/Sprites/ranger/Ranger1.png"));
        // moving Left
        ranger3 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(
                "/Images/Sprites/ranger/Ranger2.png"));
        ranger4 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(
                "/Images/Sprites/ranger/Ranger3.png"));
        // moving Right
        ranger5 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(
                "/Images/Sprites/ranger/Ranger4.png"));
        ranger6 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(
                "/Images/Sprites/ranger/Ranger5.png"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    array();

}

public void array() {
    rangerA = new ImageIcon[6];
    {
        rangerA[0] = new ImageIcon(ranger1);
        rangerA[1] = new ImageIcon(ranger2);
        rangerA[2] = new ImageIcon(ranger3);
        rangerA[3] = new ImageIcon(ranger4);
        rangerA[4] = new ImageIcon(ranger5);
        rangerA[5] = new ImageIcon(ranger6);
    }
}

public void move() {

    AbstractAction moveUp = new AbstractAction() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Move up");
        }

    };

    this.getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), "moveUp");
    this.getActionMap().put("moveUp", moveUp);

    X += dX;
    Y += dY;

    dX = 0;
    dY = 0;

    if (movingRight || movingLeft) {
        moving = true;
    }

}

}
```

I am trying it to output that it will move up in the console so that i can lean how to make new KeyBindings but I don't know why it dosn't work. Any solutions/tips will be much appreciated.

P.S. I am new to Java so sorry for simple mistakes and I am also aware of the wild loop in the main game window class.

EDIT: move() is called every few miliseconds in a seperate timer class.

Comment: You never call `move()`... That's where the Key Bindings would be added. But you shouldn't be adding them in such a method anyway (if `move()` is intended to actually move the Ranger)

Comment: ie. add the bindings in the constructor of your class.

Comment: OK I jave now sorted it I think it was becuase I was creating more and more of the keybindings as the move() was being called every milisecond in my timer class. So thanks camikr for telling me to move the bindings to the contructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W")` doesn't do what you think it does.  Using this form requires a verbose description of the action, ie `typed w`.

For this reason, I never use it.  Instead, I prefer to use `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0)` which is much more direct

See [`KeyStroke#getKeyStroke(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke(int,%20int)) for more details.

You're also not binding the key strokes as you never call the `move` method.  Instead, bind the key strokes in the classes constructor or some other method which should be called only once.